# Spring Security and WebLogic 12c security realm

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, weblogic

I have Spring Boot beased web application using Spring Security 4.0.2 for authentication. My app deployed to WebLogic 12c with configured security realm.

I want to configure Spring Security authorization through WebLogic security realm.
I tried finding in net but unable to get any working and actual samples which explains the Weblogic/Spring-Sec working together.

I need Spring Security java configuration sample for WebLogic security realm.

Can anyone help me with this issue?